# how i can trace an IP using delphi

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe, traceroute

i need trace the route of an ip, actually i am using the `TIdTraceRoute` indy component from the `idTraceRoute` unit.

```
   IdTraceRoute1:= TIdTraceRoute.Create(Self);
   IdTraceRoute1.ResolveHostNames:= True;
   IdTraceRoute1.ReceiveTimeout:= 5000;
   IdTraceRoute1.OnReply:= TraceRoute;

    IdTraceRoute1.Host:= 'www.google.com';
    IdTraceRoute1.Trace;


procedure TForm1.TraceRoute(ASender: TComponent;
  const AReplyStatus: TReplyStatus);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add(AReplyStatus.FromIpAddress);
end;
```

but always return.

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
```

exist another way of trace an ip maybe using windows api or using another indy component?

actually i am using delphi-xe and Windows 7.

Comment: add tag `indy`, problem is there

Comment: yes, there is an API to avoid Indy, consult here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366051(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote a entry on my blog, wich can help you.

[`Building a traceroute application with IP geolocation using delphi`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/building-a-traceroute-application-with-ip-geolocation-using-delphi/)

Answer (score 1):

Trace is basically based on sending ICMP packets starting with a TTL of 1 and increasing it until reaching the destination. Because each router decrease the TTL, and when it reaches 0 an error is returned to the caller, it can be used to track the "route" packets takes. Note that to work the ICMP protocol must not be stopped by a firewall. ICMP is a protocol that runs atop IP, like TCP does. It **doesn't** use TCP. You could code a traceroute utility just using ICMP. But does the Windows tracert utility work on your system?